# Aapt2 error in Android Studio 3.1.1

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, aapt2

I updated android studio from 2.2 to 3.1 and it always give me `aapt2 error` and build failed. I added `android.enableAapt2=false` in gradle.properties and my project build successfully with a warning:
`The option 'android.enableAapt2' is deprecated and should not be used anymore.
Use 'android.enableAapt2=true' to remove this warning.
It will be removed at the end of 2018.`

The most serious thing is that I can't run the app on my mobile and virtual devices. The error `Failed to execute aapt`

**The details:**
**Run build**

```
org.gradle..ReportedException: org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexWithInstantRunDependenciesApkForDebug'.
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:139)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.executeTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:109)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.call(GradleBuildController.java:78)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.call(GradleBuildController.java:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:152)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.doBuild(GradleBuildController.java:100)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:75)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.run(ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:62)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ValidatingBuildActionRunner.run(ValidatingBuildActionRunner.java:32)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$1.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:40)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:51)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:47)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:39)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:32)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:69)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:45)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:62)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:82)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:295)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexWithInstantRunDependenciesApkForDebug'.
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultExceptionAnalyser.transform(DefaultExceptionAnalyser.java:74)
    at org.gradle.initialization.MultipleBuildFailuresExceptionAnalyser.transform(MultipleBuildFailuresExceptionAnalyser.java:47)
    at org.gradle.initialization.StackTraceSanitizingExceptionAnalyser.transform(StackTraceSanitizingExceptionAnalyser.java:30)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:137)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.executeTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:109)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.call(GradleBuildController.java:78)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.call(GradleBuildController.java:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:152)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.doBuild(GradleBuildController.java:100)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:75)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.run(ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:62)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ValidatingBuildActionRunner.run(ValidatingBuildActionRunner.java:32)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$1.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:40)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:51)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:47)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:39)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:32)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:69)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:45)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:30)
```

**Java compiler**
`Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException`

**When I enable AAPT2, the log details:**
    `Configure project :app useNewCruncher has been deprecated. It will be removed in a future version of the gradle plugin. New cruncher is now always enabled.
C:\Users\??\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\031c62276958579ac6449e5bad72b0ac\res\anim\abc_tooltip_exit.xml: error: file not found.
C:\Users\??\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\031c62276958579ac6449e5bad72b0ac\res\drawable-hdpi-v4\abc_ic_menu_share_mtrl_alpha.png: error: file not found.
C:\Users\??\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\031c62276958579ac6449e5bad72b0ac\res\drawable\abc_btn_colored_material.xml: error: file not found.
C:\Users\??\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\031c62276958579ac6449e5bad72b0ac\res\drawable-hdpi-v4\abc_textfield_search_default_mtrl_alpha.9.png: error: file not found.
C:\Users\??\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\031c62276958579ac6449e5bad72b0ac\res\layout\abc_action_bar_up_container.xml: error: file not found.
C:\Users\??\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\031c62276958579ac6449e5bad72b0ac\res\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\abc_text_select_handle_middle_mtrl_light.png: error: file not found.
C:\Users\??\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\031c62276958579ac6449e5bad72b0ac\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\abc_ab_share_pack_mtrl_alpha.9.png: error: file not found.
C:\Users\??\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\031c62276958579ac6449e5bad72b0ac\res\drawable-hdpi-v4\abc_scrubber_control_to_pressed_mtrl_005.png: error: file not found.
C:\Users\??\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\031c62276958579ac6449e5bad72b0ac\res\layout\abc_search_dropdown_item_icons_2line.xml: error: file not found.
C:\Users\??\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\031c62276958579ac6449e5bad72b0ac\res\drawable-hdpi-v4\abc_scrubber_control_to_pressed_mtrl_000.png: error: file not found.
C:\Users\??\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\031c62276958579ac6449e5bad72b0ac\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\abc_text_select_handle_middle_mtrl_light.png: error: file not found.
C:\Users\??\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\031c62276958579ac6449e5bad72b0ac\res\drawable-xxxhdpi-v4\abc_text_select_handle_right_mtrl_dark.png: error: file not found.
C:\Users\??\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\031c62276958579ac6449e5bad72b0ac\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_dark.9.png: error: file not found.
C:\Users\??\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\031c62276958579ac6449e5bad72b0ac\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\abc_textfield_search_default_mtrl_alpha.9.png: error: file not found.
C:\Users\??\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\031c62276958579ac6449e5bad72b0ac\res\color\abc_secondary_text_material_light.xml: error: file not found.
C:\Users\??\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\031c62276958579ac6449e5bad72b0ac\res\drawable\abc_btn_default_mtrl_shape.xml: error: file not found.
C:\Users\??\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\031c62276958579ac6449e5bad72b0ac\res\color\abc_primary_text_disable_only_material_light.xml: error: file not found.
C:\Users\??\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\031c62276958579ac6449e5bad72b0ac\res\drawable-ldrtl-xxhdpi-v17\abc_ic_menu_copy_mtrl_am_alpha.png: error: file not found.
C:\Users\??\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\031c62276958579ac6449e5bad72b0ac\res\layout\abc_screen_simple_overlay_action_mode.xml: error: file not found.
C:\Users\??\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\031c62276958579ac6449e5bad72b0ac\res\color\abc_primary_text_material_light.xml: error: file not found.
C:\Users\??\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\031c62276958579ac6449e5bad72b0ac\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\abc_textfield_search_activated_mtrl_alpha.9.png: error: file not found.
C:\Users\??\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\031c62276958579ac6449e5bad72b0ac\res\layout\abc_popup_menu_header_item_layout.xml: error: file not found.
C:\Users\??\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\031c62276958579ac6449e5bad72b0ac\res\drawable-hdpi-v4\abc_ic_menu_cut_mtrl_alpha.png: error: file not found.
C:\Users\??\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\031c62276958579ac6449e5bad72b0ac\res\drawable-ldrtl-xhdpi-v17\abc_spinner_mtrl_am_alpha.9.png: error: file not found.
C:\Users\??\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\031c62276958579ac6449e5bad72b0ac\res\drawable-mdpi-v4\abc_text_select_handle_left_mtrl_dark.png: error: file not found.
C:\Users\??\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\031c62276958579ac6449e5bad72b0ac\res\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\abc_ic_star_black_36dp.png: error: file not found.
C:\Users\??\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\031c62276958579ac6449e5bad72b0ac\res\drawable\abc_edit_text_material.xml: error: file not found.
C:\Users\??\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\031c62276958579ac6449e5bad72b0ac\res\drawable-hdpi-v4\abc_textfield_search_activated_mtrl_alpha.9.png: error: file not found.
C:\Users\??\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\031c62276958579ac6449e5bad72b0ac\res\layout\select_dialog_multichoice_material.xml: error: file not found.
C:\Users\??\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-compat-27.1.1.aar\89bc5b5be730920c1779275773f888ad\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\notification_bg_normal.9.png: error: file not found.
C:\Users\??\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\031c62276958579ac6449e5bad72b0ac\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\abc_list_focused_holo.9.png: error: file not found.
C:\Users\??\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\031c62276958579ac6449e5bad72b0ac\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\abc_btn_radio_to_on_mtrl_000.png: error: file not found.
C:\Users\??\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\031c62276958579ac6449e5bad72b0ac\res\drawable-mdpi-v4\abc_textfield_search_activated_mtrl_alpha.9.png: error: file not found.
C:\Users\??\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\031c62276958579ac6449e5bad72b0ac\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\abc_btn_radio_to_on_mtrl_015.png: error: file not found.
C:\Users\??\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\031c62276958579ac6449e5bad72b0ac\res\drawable-mdpi-v4\abc_ic_menu_cut_mtrl_alpha.png: error: file not found.
C:\Users\??\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\031c62276958579ac6449e5bad72b0ac\res\layout\abc_screen_toolbar.xml: error: file not found.
C:\Users\??\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\031c62276958579ac6449e5bad72b0ac\res\color-v23\abc_tint_btn_checkable.xml: error: file not found.
C:\Users\??\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\031c62276958579ac6449e5bad72b0ac\res\layout\abc_tooltip.xml: error: file not found.
C:\Users\??\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-compat-27.1.1.aar\89bc5b5be730920c1779275773f888ad\res\drawable-hdpi-v4\notification_bg_normal_pressed.9.png: error: file not found.
C:\Users\??\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\031c62276958579ac6449e5bad72b0ac\res\drawable\abc_list_selector_background_transition_holo_light.xml: error: file not found.
C:\Users\??\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\031c62276958579ac6449e5bad72b0ac\res\drawable\abc_switch_thumb_material.xml: error: file not found.
C:\Users\??\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\031c62276958579ac6449e5bad72b0ac\res\drawable-hdpi-v4\abc_list_pressed_holo_dark.9.png: error: file not found.
C:\Users\??\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\031c62276958579ac6449e5bad72b0ac\res\anim\abc_fade_in.xml: error: file not found.
C:\Users\??\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\031c62276958579ac6449e5bad72b0ac\res\color-v23\abc_btn_colored_borderless_text_material.xml: error: file not found.
C:\Users\??\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\031c62276958579ac6449e5bad72b0ac\res\drawable-ldrtl-xxxhdpi-v17\abc_ic_menu_copy_mtrl_am_alpha.png: error: file not found.
C:\Users\??\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-compat-27.1.1.aar\89bc5b5be730920c1779275773f888ad\res\layout\notification_template_custom_big.xml: error: file not found.
C:\Users\??\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\031c62276958579ac6449e5bad72b0ac\res\drawable-ldrtl-hdpi-v17\abc_ic_menu_cut_mtrl_alpha.png: error: file not found.
C:\Users\??\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\031c62276958579ac6449e5bad72b0ac\res\drawable-hdpi-v4\abc_ic_menu_copy_mtrl_am_alpha.png: error: file not found.
C:\Users\??\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\031c62276958579ac6449e5bad72b0ac\res\drawable-hdpi-v4\abc_cab_background_top_mtrl_alpha.9.png: error: file not found.
C:\Users\??\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\031c62276958579ac6449e5bad72b0ac\res\drawable-mdpi-v4\abc_ic_commit_search_api_mtrl_alpha.png: error: file not found.
C:\Users\??\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\031c62276958579ac6449e5bad72b0ac\res\drawable-ldrtl-xxxhdpi-v17\abc_ic_menu_cut_mtrl_alpha.png: error: file not found.
C:\Users\??\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\031c62276958579ac6449e5bad72b0ac\res\anim\abc_tooltip_enter.xml: error: file not found.
C:\Users\??\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\031c62276958579ac6449e5bad72b0ac\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\abc_cab_background_top_mtrl_alpha.9.png: error: file not found.
C:\Users\??\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\031c62276958579ac6449e5bad72b0ac\res\drawable-hdpi-v4\abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_dark.9.png: error: file not found.
C:\Users\??\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-compat-27.1.1.aar\89bc5b5be730920c1779275773f888ad\res\drawable-v21\notification_action_background.xml: error: file not found.
C:\Users\??\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\031c62276958579ac6449e5bad72b0ac\res\layout\abc_dialog_title_material.xml: error: file not found.
C:\Users\??\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\031c62276958579ac6449e5bad72b0ac\res\drawable\abc_spinner_textfield_background_material.xml: error: file not found.
C:\Users\??\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\031c62276958579ac6449e5bad72b0ac\res\color\abc_primary_text_material_dark.xml: error: file not found.
C:\Users\??\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\031c62276958579ac6449e5bad72b0ac\res\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\abc_spinner_mtrl_am_alpha.9.png: error: file not found.
C:\Users\??\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\031c62276958579ac6449e5bad72b0ac\res\color\abc_secondary_text_material_dark.xml: error: file not found.
C:\Users\??\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\031c62276958579ac6449e5bad72b0ac\res\drawable-watch-v20\abc_dialog_material_background.xml: error: file not found.
C:\Users\??\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\031c62276958579ac6449e5bad72b0ac\res\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\abc_list_divider_mtrl_alpha.9.png: error: file not found.
C:\Users\??\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\031c62276958579ac6449e5bad72b0ac\res\anim\abc_popup_exit.xml: error: file not found.
C:\Users\??\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\031c62276958579ac6449e5bad72b0ac\res\drawable-mdpi-v4\abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_light.9.png: error: file not found.
C:\Users\??\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\031c62276958579ac6449e5bad72b0ac\res\drawable-ldrtl-mdpi-v17\abc_ic_menu_cut_mtrl_alpha.png: error: file not found.
C:\Users\??\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\031c62276958579ac6449e5bad72b0ac\res\anim\abc_fade_out.xml: error: file not found.
C:\Users\??\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-compat-27.1.1.aar\89bc5b5be730920c1779275773f888ad\res\layout\notification_action.xml: error: file not found.
C:\Users\??\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\031c62276958579ac6449e5bad72b0ac\res\drawable-xxxhdpi-v4\abc_scrubber_control_to_pressed_mtrl_005.png: error: file not found.
C:\Users\??\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\031c62276958579ac6449e5bad72b0ac\res\drawable-xxxhdpi-v4\abc_scrubber_control_to_pressed_mtrl_000.png: error: file not found.
C:\Users\??\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\031c62276958579ac6449e5bad72b0ac\res\drawable\abc_ic_go_search_api_material.xml: error: file not found.
C:\Users\??\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\031c62276958579ac6449e5bad72b0ac\res\drawable-mdpi-v4\abc_btn_check_to_on_mtrl_000.png: error: file not found.
C:\Users\??\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-compat-27.1.1.aar\89bc5b5be730920c1779275773f888ad\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\notification_bg_low_normal.9.png: error: file not found.
C:\Users\??\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\031c62276958579ac6449e5bad72b0ac\res\color\abc_tint_edittext.xml: error: file not found.
C:\Users\??\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\031c62276958579ac6449e5bad72b0ac\res\drawable-v21\abc_btn_colored_material.xml: error: file not found.
C:\Users\??\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\031c62276958579ac6449e5bad72b0ac\res\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\abc_text_select_handle_middle_mtrl_dark.png: error: file not found.
C:\Users\??\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-compat-27.1.1.aar\89bc5b5be730920c1779275773f888ad\res\layout\notification_action_tombstone.xml: error: file not found.
C:\Users\??\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\031c62276958579ac6449e5bad72b0ac\res\drawable-xxxhdpi-v4\abc_ic_menu_paste_mtrl_am_alpha.png: error: file not found.
C:\Users\??\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\031c62276958579ac6449e5bad72b0ac\res\drawable-hdpi-v4\abc_text_select_handle_left_mtrl_dark.png: error: file not found.
C:\Users\??\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\031c62276958579ac6449e5bad72b0ac\res\drawable-xxxhdpi-v4\abc_ic_star_black_48dp.png: error: file not found.
C:\Users\??\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\031c62276958579ac6449e5bad72b0ac\res\drawable-mdpi-v4\abc_scrubber_control_off_mtrl_alpha.png: error: file not found.
Task :app:mergeDebugResources 
Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
BUILD FAILED in 5s
11 actionable tasks: 9 executed, 2 up-to-date`

**Information of my Android Studio**
SDK Tools:26.1.1
Gradle version:4.4
Plugin version:3.1
platform version:API 27

I have seen some answers in other questions but they don't work for me. Hope my details are enough for you to solve my problem.

Comment: What is your build-tools and compile sdk version?

Comment: `:app:transformDexWithInstantRunDependenciesApkForDebug'` this is probably related with **Instant Run**. Try to disable Instant Run.

Comment: This is a bug in 3.0.1 that comes from disabling AAPT2. Start a new bug with the error  you get when AAPT2 is enabled and attach the full build log. Let's solve that issue, since AAPT1 will be deprecated soon

Comment: @XoXo compileSdkVersion 26, buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'

Comment: @IzabelaOrlowska I enable AAPT2 and it gives me `AAPT2 error: check logs for details`. Where can I check logs?

Comment: change compileSdkVersion to 27 and update buildToolsVersion to 27.1.0

Comment: You should be able to find the build log in the android studio 'build' tab. If you can't find it you can go to your project in a terminal and run "gradlew clean assembleDebug" and post the contents here.

Comment: @IzabelaOrlowska I readded the log in my question.

Comment: @LibraTang can you add the whole output of "gradlew clean assembleDebug" not just the stacktrace? It will tell you which tasks were run and what the AAPT error is

Comment: @XoXo I change my buildToolsVersion to 27.0.3(failed to download 27.1.0), but it doesn't work.

Comment: @ישואוהבאותך now i can run the app on my mobile but still can't run on emulator. It shows "waiting for target device to come online" all the time.

Comment: @IzabelaOrlowska I'm sorry but I typed "gradlew assembleDebug" in terminal and it shows me "ERROR: JAVA_HOME is not set and no 'java' command could be found in your PATH.

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation." But I've already put jre into environment.

Comment: You also need to set the environment variable JAVA_HOME to point to your jdk

Comment: @IzabelaOrlowska Thank you so much. I finally added the log to my question...

Comment: @LibraTang no problem :) one last question - did you replace your username with "??" in the errors or was it exactly like that in the log?

Comment: @IzabelaOrlowska my username is in Chinese...

Comment: @LibraTang please see my answer for this issue - basically try with android gradle plugin 3.2.0-alpha11

Comment: @IzabelaOrlowska I'll try. Thank you!

Comment: @IzabelaOrlowska It worked!!! With no other errors. Thank you for solving my problem!

Comment: @LibraTang haha no worries, I'm happy it worked :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you might be experiencing issues with AAPT2 not handling non-ascii characters on windows properly. This has been solved in the newest 3.2.0 alphas. Try replacing the android gradle plugin in your build.gradle file to match:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0-alpha11'
```

Note: since you updated from 2.2 to 3.1.1 directly, after fixing this issue you can also experience other errors from AAPT2 - it is much stricter than AAPT (it's better to fail early at build time than to run into runtime crashes). If you run into them checkout the [migration guide](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#aapt2). If the guide doesn't have enough info create a new bug here or on the [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=192708&template=840533).

Answer (score 2):

The warning just tells you to remove **android.enableAapt2=false** from **gradle.properties**.
It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

To whom ever this might help later on,
I solved my problem by removing the tag `android:fullBackUpContent=""` from the manifest file,
Intellisense from android studio had made me put it there and due to trust, you may also spend 12 hours looking for your problem, But, that is it
Good luck